# SimpleStorage 100% in Yul

Tags: solidity, yul

What would a solidity simple storage contract look like 100% in yul?

I haven't seen a solid example. I know what this would look like in huff, but would love to see a yul example.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 myNumber;

    function storeNumber(uint256 newNumber) public {
        myNumber = newNumber;
    }

    function readNumber() public view returns(uint256) {
        return myNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look like this:

```js
object "YYSimpleStorage" {
     code {
        // Contract deployment
        datacopy(0, dataoffset("runtime"), datasize("runtime"))
        return(0, datasize("runtime"))
     }
     object "runtime" {
        code {
            // The MAIN function of the contract, function dispatcher
            switch selector()
            // cast sig "storeNumber(uint256)"
            case 0xb6339418 {
                storeNumber(decodeAsUint(0))
                returnTrue()
            }
            // cast sig "readNumber()"
            case 0xb63d343f{
                returnUint(readNumber())
            }
            default {
                revert(0, 0)
            }

            function storeNumber(newNumber) {
                sstore(0, newNumber)
            }

            function readNumber() -> storedNumber{
                storedNumber := sload(0)
            }

            /* ---------- calldata decoding functions ----------- */
            function selector() -> s {
                s := div(calldataload(0), 0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
            }

            function decodeAsUint(offset) -> v {
                let pos := add(4, mul(offset, 0x20))
                if lt(calldatasize(), add(pos, 0x20)) {
                    revert(0, 0)
                }
                v := calldataload(pos)
            }

            function returnUint(v) {
                mstore(0, v)
                return(0, 0x20)
            }

            function returnTrue() {
                returnUint(1)
            }
        }
     }
}
```

And you could compile it like this:

```
solc --strict-assembly --optimize --optimize-runs 200 yul/YYSimpleStorage.yul --bin
```